# Getting a pointer to a instance attribute in python using Cython

Tags: python, pointers, cython, cpython

Reference: https://edcjones.tripod.com/refcount.html

Returning a PyObject* from a function requires the function to first increment the strong reference count of PyObject*.

Consider this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._v = value

    def value(self):
        return self._value

a = A(2)
a.value() # prints 2
```

How do I get a pointer of `self._value` such that it always tracks the `self._value` variable using Cython?